# Concatenating lines from text file - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, file-io

I have a text file in a format like so,

Text:

```
-- Begin 
  Line1
  Line2
  Line3
      ^
-- Begin
  Line1
  Line2
  Line3
  Line4
      ^
.
.
.
.
```

I basically want to put `Line1` to `Line(whatever)` between the lines `--Begin` to `^`
in an array so each element in the array is bunch of lines Example of array

```
Array =  [("Line1"  & vbNewLine & "Line 2") , ("Line1"  & vbNewLine & "Line 2" & vbNewLine & "Line 3") ... ]
```

But basically want to store each element in the array in a cell. (Might not even need to use an array) ...

Not sure if this is even possible in excel VBA, but this is what I've tried so far

```
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim DataLine As String
    Dim Lines As Variant
    Dim j As Integer


    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open "C:..." For Input As #FileNum


 While Not EOF(FileNum)
       Line Input #FileNum, DataLine

      If InStr(DataLine, "-- Begin") > 0 Then
        nextLinecounter = 1

      ElseIf InStr(DataLine, "^") > 0 Then
        nextLinecounter = 0
        j = j + 1

      ElseIf nextLinecounter = 1 Then
       Lines(j) = DataLine + .. Somehow concatenate next lines into array

     End If


Wend
```

I'm stuck how to skip next line and append it to the current entry, any way of doing this thanks.

Comment: @mehow How would i use readAll, and set boundaries to where to start and stop reading all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would do it a bit differently. Using a more up to date approach for file reading.

See more details on how to read *.txt files in VBA - [**`here`**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/reading-txt-files-from-vba/)

Note: you need to add references to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` via VBE -> Tools -> References

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReadTxtFile()

    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim oFS As TextStream

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Desktop\foo.txt"

    If Not fileExist(filePath) Then GoTo FileDoesntExist

    On Error GoTo Err

    ReDim arr(0) As String
    Dim s As String

    Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath)
    Do While Not oFS.AtEndOfStream
        Dim line As String
        line = oFS.ReadLine
        If InStr(line, "-- Begin") = 0 And InStr(line, "^") = 0 Then
            s = s & line
        End If
        If InStr(line, "^") > 0 Then
            arr(UBound(arr)) = s
            ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
            s = vbNullString
        End If
    Loop
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
    oFS.Close

    Dim k As Long
    For k = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print k, arr(k)
    Next k
    Exit Sub

FileDoesntExist:
    MsgBox "File Doesn't Exist", vbCritical, "File not found!"
    Exit Sub

Err:
    MsgBox "Error while reading the file.", vbCritical, vbNullString
    oFS.Close
    Exit Sub

End Sub


Function fileExist(path As String) As Boolean
    fileExist = IIf(Dir(path) <> vbNullString, True, False)
End Function
```

the `foo.txt` looks like this

```
-- Begin 
  Line1
  Line2
  Line3
      ^
-- Begin
  Line1
  Line2
  Line3
  Line4
      ^
```

your array looks like this

[image]

Comment: for this doesn't the arr have one line as each element .. Is there a way to store multiple lines in each element ?

Comment: If I'm reading it right after every so many elements there exists an element with multiple lines... So in your .txt file `arr(4) = Line1
  Line2
  Line3` ?

Comment: and i don't think this works .. does arr(UBound(arr)) & vbNewLine .. append all the lines before or ?

Comment: Ive modified to the code so it inserts each block of txt at separated index. is this what you want?

Comment: @Thatdude1 what do you mean `i dont think this works`? what does not work for you?

Comment: Thanks so much for you time mehow i got it too work, and yes that it is what i wanted... Cheers!

Comment: phew.. I seriously started to worry :P well, im glad it works